# python s3 using boto, says 'attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have a connection that works as I can list buckets, but having issues when trying to add a object.

```
conn = S3Connection(awskey, awssecret)

key = Key(mybucket)

key.key = p.sku
key.set_contents_from_filename(fullpathtofile)
```

I get the error:

```
'attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

the error is in the file:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-package/boto-2.obl-py2.6.egg/boto/s3/key.py' line # 539
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Key` expects a bucket object as its first parameter (possibly created by `conn.create_bucket()`).

It looks like `mybucket` isn't a bucket, but a string, so the call fails.

Comment: thanks, that was it.  btw k.set_acl('public-read') doesn't work, am I missing something?

Comment: @blank: No idea about `set_acl`

Answer (score 13):

Just replace:

```
key = Key(mybucket)
```

with:

```
mybucket = "foo"
bucketobj = conn.get_bucket(mybucket)
mykey = Key(bucketobj)
```

Expanding on sth's comment, you can't pass a string, it needs to be a bucket object.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I would do this:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket("mybucketname")
key = bucket.new_key("mynewkeyname")
key.set_contents_from_filename('path_to_local_file', policy='public-read')
```

Mitch

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
mybucket = s3.Bucket('mybucketName')
```

Now you will get the s3 bucket object. You were getting the string.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import boto.s3.connection

accessKeyId = 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
secretKey = 'YOUR_AWS_SECERT_KEY_ID'
host = 'HOST'

S3 = boto.connect_s3(
  aws_access_key_id = accessKeyId,
  aws_secret_access_key = secretKey,
  host = host,
  port = PORT,
  calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
)


def upload_objects():

    try:
        bucket_name = "bucket name" #s3 bucket name
        root_path = 'model/' # local folder for upload
        my_bucket = S3.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
            path = path.replace("\\","/")
            directory_name = path.replace(root_path,"")
            for file in files:
                if(file != ".DS_Store"):
                    full_key_name = os.path.join(path, file)
                    k = my_bucket.new_key(full_key_name)
                    k.set_contents_from_filename('/model/'+directory_name+'/'+file)

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

upload_objects()
```